Movie in which someone use a (flying) disc as a weapon (projectile)
I am looking for the name of a movie I saw back in the 90's or beginning of the 2000's (before 2006 for certain). All I remember is someone (or maybe a cyborg with flesh, or a human-like alien, but humanoid for sure) attacking other with disc he may have fire from a device on his forearm. And I might be wrong but as I recall it happens in a parking in a building at some point. The disc itself can not just stop like that unless it is stabilized by magnets (I think).

Possible duplicate? This sounds like I Come In Peace with Dolph Lundgren from 1990.

it might be that since I recall seeing the guy. (checking now...). That's it. How do a make the question "answered" when the answer is in the comment?

@Walt - its not a duplicate just because the answer is the same.  I think you should upgrade to an answer and can get the credit for the find.

Fair enough - will post as an answer.

I Come in Peace (AKA Dark Angel), an action film from 1990. From IMDb:

Jack Caine (Dolph Lundgren) is a Houston vice cop who's forgotten the rule book. [...] Along with F.B.I. agent Lawrence Smith, the two investigate a spate of mysterious deaths; normal non-junkies dying of massive heroin overdoses and bearing the same horrific puncture marks on the forehead. This, coupled with Caine's own evidence, indicates an alien force is present on the streets of Houston, killing and gathering stocks of a rare drug found only in the brain... 

The alien shoots people with flying metal disks from a device on his arm, which can be seen in the trailer around 0:42:




I don't know why that one isn't a cult classic :P
